# Where to report bugs involving opencl in ubuntu?

Tags: opencl

I assume the problem is the AMD OpenCL driver because I can duplicate the bug only on a system with AMD boards.  Does not occur on NVidia systems.  Looked into the problem when I found I was occasionally running out of disk space for no good reason.  I went to /var/log and looked at syslog.  First thing I noticed were the huge log size. Grep'ed for "error" and found  1,000,000's of errors  all the same:

```
Jan 23 23:07:17 jysdualxeon kernel: [  381.590086] [drm:amdgpu_cs_ioctl [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to initialize parser -125!
```

A reboot stops the errors from being written, other than everything being slow, the system seems to be working ok.

I can duplicate the error as follows:  With a program running an OpenCL app, I run the tool "clinfo".  It may have to be run as many as 3 times before the bug kicks in.  Normally clinfo takes 1-2 seconds to complete.  With another app using OpenCL, the clinfo programs hangs.  It make take 2 minutes to complete and give a report.  There are no problems in the report, just takes too long generate it.  Looking at syslog I see it increasing by huge amouns in only seconds

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 15171032 Jan 23 23:08 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 22775421 Jan 23 23:13 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 29911745 Jan 23 23:14 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 30435769 Jan 23 23:14 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 30711297 Jan 23 23:15 syslog
```

With my small 128gb sdd, the system dies in a few days unless I delete the files

[EDIT] also, the app that was actually using OpenCL dies when this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the place to report a bug for OpenCL:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/libclcxx